# If page url = anchor in list, trigger mouseover + make bold

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, html-lists

Headline says it all. What i am trying to achieve is to check onload urls in menu (multiple ul since it also has submenus) and if it equals, make it bold and trigger mouseover event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content > ul > li a[href]').filter(function() {return this.href.pathname === window.location.pathname;}).css('font-weight','bold');
    $('#content > ul > li a[href]').filter(function() {return this.href.pathname === window.location.pathname;}).trigger('mouseover');
});

<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="displayID('biography');">Biography</a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/Commercial_photography" onmouseover="displayID('commercial-photography');">Commercial photography</a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/Fine_art_photography" onmouseover="displayID('fine-art-photography');">Fine art photography</a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/Action" onmouseover="displayID('action');">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/Video" onmouseover="displayID('video');">Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="displayID('links');">Links</a></li>
</ul>
```

I assume there is just a very simple mistake since I am not really familiar with jquery, so I really appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `href` property of a link is a string, which has no `pathname` property.

Use `this.pathname`, instead of `this.href.pathname` to solve your issue:

```
function(){
    return this.pathname === location.pathname &&
           !/^#/.test(this.getAttribute('href'))   //The href at HTML may not 
}                                                 //start with #
```

Edit after comment:
The `getAttribute` method is used to get the original `href` attribute, because `this.href` does not contain `#`, but `http://fullpath/etc/file#`.

Comment: of course, my mistake! thank you. Just one more question I've noticed, it also makes links with # go bold, such as <a href="#" onmouseover="displayID('biography');">Biography</a>. Is there a way to exclude this?

Comment: This is awesome! only for future reference, now it selects ONLY links with #, but it can easily be solved by negation  :) thank you Rob!